# I enabled mem_cache and cache then disabled them, now my apache2 server won't respond

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, memcache

Yikes.  I just attempted to enable cache and mem_cache using `sudo a2enmod mem_cache` and `sudo a2enmod cache` on my Ubuntu lucid server.  Now my apache2 server doesn't respond at all.  I tried `sudo a2dismod cache` and `sudo a2dismod mem_cache` but now apache does not respond.  Tried restarting apache2 and rebooting, but no dice.

`sudo apache2ctl fullstatus` gives me:

```
w3m: Can't load http://localhost:80/server-status
```

Help!  What else does a2enmod change that I can revert back?

Comment: Anything out of the apache error log?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use it. They have removed it from Apache HTTPD 2.4. There's no much point in getting an obsolete feature to work.

Answer (score 0):

Check the actual Apache configuration file, located usually at `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` or `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and check under the `Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support` section, to make sure everything is kosher.

Make sure the paths are correct, etc.

E.g.

```
LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
```

[***You may also want to check the mod_cache documentation on Apache's site.***](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_cache.html)

Answer (score 0):

After saving my configuration files in /etc/apache2/sites-available, I ended up just [purging and reinstalling everything apache using the instructions here](http://dancingpenguinsoflight.com/2009/02/how-to-completely-reset-an-apache-instance-in-ubuntu/). Then I copied back the configuration files, re-enabled my sites and any needed plugins, and restarted apache2.  I still don't have memcache working, and I don't know what the problem was, but I'll just wait on attempting to get memcache working as it's not essential for me now.